# get mutable default arguments of func

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, signature

How do I get the mutable default arguments tuple in Python 3?

```
def foo(x=[]):
    pass
```

Failed Attempt:

```
foo.func_defaults
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_defaults'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `__defaults__`, like this

```
def foo(x=[]):
    x.append(1)

foo()
foo()
print(foo.__defaults__)
# ([1, 1],)
```

Quoting from the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/datamodel.html),

> **__defaults__**
>
> A tuple containing default argument values for those arguments that have defaults, or `None` if no arguments have a default value.

It means that, when you have a function which doesn't have a default parameter, then `__defaults__` will be `None`

```
def foo():
    pass

print(foo.__defaults__)
# None
```